# custom roles and user adminstration in ASP.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm implementing my frist web application on asp.net mvc 4 and I need to differentiate my users according to roles ( show certain menus to some roles and hide them from others) basically what i want is to manage my users and roles. I understand that security is quite an important part of my application so I don't want to risk it by implementing something not secure while there are other options for doing this.

My question is, is there something already built on MVC 4? is it apropiate for my a small site? ( I don't expect more than 50 concurrent users) is it better to implement my own user administrator? if so, where can I start? so far what I've found is the membership provider but it seems quite big for what i need, there will be no user registration instead the new users will be added by system admins.

Thanks for taking the time for reading this, any feedback will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would have recommended the default membership provider as it makes use of security industry best practices (i.e. salted hash). However, if that seems overkill, there is a simpler membership provider called [SimpleMembership Provider](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [New ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) (updated version of legacy Membership Provider).

It can be used in small application as well as large application (if you application continues to grow).

Password is encrypted with salt, so it cannot be compromise easily.

Follow the Scott Hanselman's link and see the demo. You will see how easy to set up.